# How to return Django model in a url?

Tags: python, django, django-models, axios, url-pattern

I would like my Django Model to be accessible via http://localhost:8000/teams

models.py:

```
from typing import Any
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    top_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_id
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from backend import views,models

urlpatterns = [
    path("teams/", models.Team, name="teams"),
    path("", views.home, name = "home"),
]
```

I know that object has no attribute 'get'. How can I set  it up? I tried **getattribute** but doesn't seem to work.
I want to have a url like that so I can later on download the model via axios in my react app.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to create a `ListView` which will list all the teams.

Docs for this are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).

Essentially your view might look like this;

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from backend.models import Team


class TeamListView(ListView):

    model = Team
    paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired
```

And your URL becomes;

```py
from django.urls import path
from backend.views import TeamListView

urlpatterns = [
    path("teams/", TeamListView.as_view(), name="teams"),
    path("", views.home, name = "home"),
]
```

There's an excellent site for all things related to class based views here; http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: Nice, although class based view for beginner are hard to grasp, a bit of insight for the author : https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-class-based-views-vs-function-based-view-e74b47b2e41b